# I'd like to get the sum of count(*) between several ranges

Tags: sql, count, sum, between, range

I'd like to get the sum of `count(*)` between several ranges.

For example I have 10 `select count(*)` statements from one location range to another.

I'd like to get the sum of all 10 location ranges.

```
SELECT count (*) 
FROM locn_hdr 
WHERE locn_brcd 
BETWEEN 'B2121' AND 'B2144'

SELECT count (*) 
FROM locn_hdr 
WHERE locn_brcd 
BETWEEN 'B2201' AND 'B2224'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this query in mysql:**

select (sum(if(locn_brcd between 'B2121' and 'B2144',1,0))+sum(if(locn_brcd between 'B2201' and 'B2224',1,0))) as total  from locn_hdr

Comment: send me your query to this email id justinvincent87@yahoo.com, i will check it and send you back

Comment: I'm using the example you just posted

Answer (score 0):

**If you want individual result you can use the following query:**

```
select sum(if(locn_brcd between 'B2121' and 'B2144',1,0)) as ca1, 
    sum(if(locn_brcd between 'B2201' and 'B2224',1,0)) as ca2,
    sum(if(locn_brcd between 'B2322' and 'B2344',1,0)) as ca3,
    sum(if(locn_brcd between 'B2401' and 'B2424',1,0)) as ca4,
    sum(if(locn_brcd between 'B2521' and 'B2544',1,0)) as ca5,
    sum(if(locn_brcd between 'B2601' and 'B2624',1,0)) as ca6,
    sum(if(locn_brcd between 'B0317' and 'B0340',1,0)) as ca7,
    sum(if(locn_brcd between 'B0401' and 'B0424',1,0)) as ca8,
    sum(if(locn_brcd between 'B0517' and 'B0540',1,0)) as ca9,
    sum(if(locn_brcd between 'B0601' and 'B0624',1,0)) as ca10
from locn_hd;
```